# NHibernate and using JQuery get()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I've got an ASP MVC application where I am editing a field and posting the change back via Javascript like so:

```
    "saveAndClose": function () {
    var url = baseURL + "Product/UpdateProductFamily/" + $.trim($('#Id').text()) + "/" + $('#recordValue').val();
    $.get(
    url,
    function (returnedData) {
        alert('worked');
    });
```

The call doesn't even make it to the controller, instead I get an exception in the NHibernate Session manager:

```
        private static void BeginTransaction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance;
        x.BeginTransaction();

        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = x.GetSession().GetSessionImplementation().SessionId.ToString(); 

    }
```

The x.GetSession() line errors saying "The property is already set and cannot be modified".

What's going on here?  Why is a simple JQuery get to the controller causing this NHibernate error?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to do - but if you're doing a save shouldn't you be doing a post rather than a get? Also have you tried outputting what the 'url' value is to see if it looks like a valid route?

Comment: Good questions Jen, I checked the url value and it is absolutely valid route.  As far as the Get, seems like a much lighter way to save the data (I'm passing the two values to save in the URL) versus creating a form and doing a Post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is the result of trying to set the Name of the CurrentThread after it has been set.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name.aspx

What I am not sure of, is why you need to set the name of the thread to the current session id.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :).  That's there so logging can associate session (and associated SQL Statements).  My question is more around WHY the code is even being called before my controller is even hit.

Comment: You would need show the stack trace for the InvalidOperationException  to determine how the BeginTransaction method is begin called.  Many people implement a transaction-per-request when using NHibernate in ASP.NET MVC. It could be that BeginTransaction is being called whenever a new request is made or by an ActionFilterAttribute applied to the controller/action.

Comment: Yup, I think that's what's going on

Comment: The call was unnecessary, when consulting with the guy who put that in they confirmed that it could be removed.